# How to allow assign only users with specified role?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, cancan

I have `User` model with CanCan authorisation.

So user have `role` attribute from this array: `=> ['doctor', 'patient']`

```
class Shift < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :doctor, class_name: "User", foreign_key: :user_id
  belongs_to :day

  validates :shift, presence: true
  validates :cardiologist, presence: true
end
```

How should I write validator to allow create `Shifts` only for `doctors` and not allow to create shift where `user_id` attribute is not a `patient` id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write a custom validation method. Something like this should do it for you.

```
validate :check_doctor
def check_doctor
  errors.add(:doctor, "User is not a doctor") unless self.doctor && self.doctor.role == "doctor" 
end
```

Comment: It may raise error "undefined method 'role' for nil:NilClass" if shift has no doctor.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
validate :check_for_patient

private
  def check_for_patient
    errors.add(:base, 'error message') if self.doctor && self.doctor.role == 'patient'
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, custom checkers (like in other answers) will work fine, but consider separating notion of `User` and role in the system. What if some `Doctor` want to become a `Patient`?

Maybe create separate tables for `Doctors` and `Patients`?

Thus, it would be easy to implement your check. I.e. it would be impossible to create `Shift` for `Patient`...

With STI (single table inheritance) approach it soon becomes messy to handle stuff like this (too much to handle).